# copy / paste not working in screen sharing, Mac remote, VNC on Windows

Tags: macos, remote-connection, vnc-viewer

Ventura 13.4.1 on new Mac mini (M2), Screen Sharing enabled (or Remote Management, doesn't matter), RealVNC Viewer on Windows 10 (or UltraVNC, doesn't matter). "Allow copy and paste text..." enabled in VNC viewer preferences (don't see an equivalent option on Mac side). I can copy and paste between windows of the VNC session using Alt-C, Alt-V. I can not paste from VNC viewer to Windows native window (Ctrl-V still has the previous contents of the Windows clipboard). Also can't copy/paste from Windows native window to VNC Mac window.

Tried different options in Mac sharing, different options / version of VNC on Windows, every combination of Ctrl-C/V, Cmd-C/V, Alt-C/V. The one thing I can't find is any switch for enabling remote copy/paste on the Mac side.

Comment: Mac has the options inside Remote Management > Options… [idk the equivalent in Ventura, they moved everything & made it impossible to find,  like an iPhone:\

Comment: Thanks. There are 9 checkboxes in the Remote Management Options, I have them all checked, none have anything to do with copy/paste.

Comment: There's nothing more I can test, sorry. I copy/paste between Macs all the time using Remote Management for most & Screen Sharing for some in different cities that I don't directly own. It all 'just works'. I've never tried it from a WinPC. I don't have any any more, except some in VM. BTW, I see 10 boxes to check, the last of which is 'Copy items'. It would appear all are on by default though.